# Cookie not being set in POST request, but works in HEAD request (identical code)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors, setcookie

I'm facing a peculiar issue where the browser (I've tried both Chrome and Mozilla Firefox) doesn't seem to set a cookie from a POST response, even though the `Set-Cookie` header is present in the response. When I send a similar request using the HEAD method, the cookie is set correctly.

Here's what I've verified so far:

1. The server is sending a `Set-Cookie` header in the response for both HEAD and POST requests.
2. I've inspected the network traffic using browser developer tools, and I can see the `Set-Cookie` header in the response for the POST request.
3. The code for setting the cookie on the server side is identical for both HEAD and POST requests.
4. There are no apparent errors or exceptions on the server side, and the server responds with a 200 status code.

Here's a simplified version of the relevant server-side code:

```
exports.testCookie = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const serialized = serialize('cookie', 'test-cookie', {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 120000000,
      path: '/',
      sameSite: 'Lax',
    });
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', serialized)
    res.status(200)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating user:", error);
    res.status(500).json({error: "Internal server error"});
  }
};
```

I'm puzzled by this behavior, as I would expect the browser to set the cookie as it does with HEAD requests. Are there any known issues or specific considerations when it comes to setting cookies in POST responses? Is there something I should check or configure differently on the client side to ensure the cookie is set correctly?

Comment: Browsers will allow the response to a `HEAD` request to set a cookie marked `Lax` , but they won't allow the response to a _cross-site_ `POST` request to do so. Are the Web origins of your frontend and backend [_same-site_](https://site-and-origin.securitum.com/)? If not, you'll need to either 1) make sure frontend and backend are same-site or 2) mark your cookie `SameSite=None` (and `Secure`).

Comment: I have tried marking my cookie with SameSite= None and added Secure, it still didn't work

Comment: Is the Web origin of your backend secure? Does it start with `https://`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#lax - just in case you need the documentation. How do you know it doesn't *set* the cookie? Have you actually checked in the browser, like here chrome://settings/content/all ?